# How to take user input using PyRevit?

Tags: python, revit, pyrevit

How would I take user input at various points while running a PyRevit script? I know that input('') doesn't work. I am wanting the user to input integers to perform a calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the .NET `Windows.Forms` library and display a prompt for input in a modal Windows form using `ShowDialog`.

Comment: Tkinter or wxPython would remove the need for .NET installed. If you compile the your python-script the user also don't need Python.

Answer (score 0):

There i a build in method for this. Example

```
from rpw.ui.forms import TextInput
value = TextInput('Title', default="3")
print(value)
```

More examples in the doc:
https://revitpythonwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ui/forms.html